# Facebook PHP SDK Version 5.0.0 like a post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I am trying to like a Facebook post posted from an account. I have the oauth token of the account but i cant figure out how to like a post from my php code. I have a facebook app and also have the app id and app secret for my facebook app. I want to do this using the PHP SDK Version 5.0.0.

Can anyone please help with this or direct me to the some documentation apart from the one here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe creating Facebook service is not an issue. Once created, you may set a default access token for easier access. You may then take the id of the post you want to like and do this -

```
$response = $fb->post('/'.$post_id.'/likes');
```

EDIT after Tushar's comment

```
$response = $fb->post('/'.$post_id.'/likes', array());
```

where $fb is a Facebook service with a default access token.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Have tried this. A post request needs to have an array as the second parameter. Have tried with an empty array and the above url. But it doesn't work

Comment: My bad, an empty array atleast is needed as the second parameter

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly enough the approach that i commented on Navin's answer worked just fine now.When i had tried it previously i had gotten a 'Url not recognised' error.

My code is as follows-

$test=array();
 $like=$fb->post('/'.$post_id.'/likes',$test,$token);

In the $like variable i get an object of FacebookResponse with a status of success or failure.